# Using scala sys.process with single quotes, white-space, pipes etc

Tags: scala, curl

I am trying to use scala.sys.process._ to submit a POST request to my [chronos](http://airbnb.github.io/chronos/) server with curl. Because there is white space in the command's arguments, I am using the `Seq[String]` variant of `cmd.!!`

I am building the command like so:

```
val cmd = Seq("curl", "-L", "-X POST", "-H 'Content-Type: application/json'", "-d " + jsonHash,  args.chronosHost + "/scheduler/" + jobType)
```

which produces, as expected,

```
cmd: Seq[String] = List(curl, -L, -X POST, -H 'Content-Type: application/json', -d '{"schedule":"R/2014-02-02T00:00:00Z/PT24H", "name":"Scala-Post-Test", "command":"which scalac", "epsilon":"PT15M", "owner":"myemail@thecompany.com", "async":false}', localhost:4040/scheduler/iso8601)
```

however, running this appears to mangle the `'Content-Type: application/json'` argument:

```
scala> cmd.!!
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   264    0   100  100   164   2157   3538 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 54666
res21: String =
"The HTTP header field "Accept" with value "*/* 'Content-Type:application/json'" could not be parsed.
"
```

which I don't understand. By contrast, calling `cmd.mkString(" ")` and copy+pasting into the terminal works as expected.

```
curl -L -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"schedule":"R/2014-02-02T00:00:00Z/PT24H", "name":"Scala-Post-Test", "command":"which scalac", "epsilon":"PT15M", "owner":"austin@quantifind.com", "async":false}' mapr-01.dev.quantifind.com:4040/scheduler/iso8601
```

I have tried numerous variations on the -H argument to no avail, any insight into using single quotes in sys.process._'s !! would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried variations on this as well, which generates a slew of errors, including

```
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 415</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /scheduler/iso8601. Reason:
<pre>    Unsupported Media Type</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
```

(in addition to butchering the jsonHash, ie:

```
[1/6]: '"schedule":"R/2014-02-02T00:00:00Z/PT24H"' --> <stdout>

curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host ''"schedule"'

Which makes me think it is not interpreting the -H argument correctly
```

Comment: I tried the command as I suggested in the answer on my REST service and it works. There could be an issue with how you create a string. Maybe you are missing quotes? `jsonHash` should be surrounded with single quotes. If that's not the case then it could be very unlikely different shell that you use (other than bash?). Could you paste the command string as you have right now? I noticed in the first example it had `localhost`, not `http://localhost`. I'm sure it's something minor like that.

Comment: Actually curl is ok with `localhost` :), but anyway let's look at the command. Also I noticed that it reached Jetty and Jetty reported that it does not support Media Type (json?)- could that be the reason?

Comment: I can suggest a few things: run with curl from command line and make sure it works correctly. Use the same command as a single string instead of Seq. Put it in """cmd""" quotes. If that works then it should be easy to find the problem with Seq arguments. Another thing you could do is call some well documented service on internet to test your code.

Comment: In either case I think you should use some Scala/Java libraries to do that. For example: https://github.com/spray/spray/wiki/spray-client

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to split each argument into a separate element of a sequence.

Instead of this:

```
val cmd = Seq("curl", "-L", "-X POST", "-H 'Content-Type: application/json'", "-d " + jsonHash,  args.chronosHost + "/scheduler/" + jobType)
```

you need to write this:

```
val cmd = Seq("curl", "-L", "-X", "POST", "-H", "'Content-Type: application/json'", "-d " + jsonHash,  args.chronosHost + "/scheduler/" + jobType)
```

It puts each element of a sequence as an argument on a command line. So `"-H 'Content-Type...` looks like a single argument to `curl` while it should be 2.

Here is a simple way to test:

```
import scala.sys.process._
val cmd = Seq("find", "/dev/null", "-name", "null") // works
// does not work: val cmd = Seq("find", "/dev/null", "-name null")
val res = cmd.!!
println(res)
```

Comment: Posted a follow up in original question

Comment: What I mean you could try is also something like `val cmd = Seq("curl", """all kinds of args here localhost:8080""")`

Answer (score 14):

Most of the other answers are a bit faffy, use the following trick to get Bash to do all the quote handling etc etc for you

```
import scala.sys.process._

Seq("bash", "-c", bashLine) !
```

For easier Googling myself: bash execute process sys.process pipe string scala

As a `String` pimp method (easy copy pasting)

```
import scala.sys.process._

implicit class PimpedString(bashLine: String) {
  def !!!: Int = Seq("bash", "-c", bashLine) !
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I also had a hard time to make this work. Enlighten by Aleksey, below worked for me. Note that, surprisingly, there is no extra quote (or double quote) for Content-type:

```
val deploy = Seq("curl", "-X", "POST", s"$ip/v2/apps", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-d", s"@$containerJson")
println(deploy.!!)
```

Comment: I had the same problem. Extra quotes worked locally but not when called from inside a docker container.