# Using HttpURLConnection to submit a json POST request

Tags: java, json, scala, curl, httprequest

I am trying to submit a json post request using HttpURLConnection in Scala. I followed along to two tutorials and produced this:

```
def sendPost(url: String, jsonHash: String) {
  val conn: HttpURLConnection = new URL(url).openConnection().asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]
  conn.setRequestMethod("POST")
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
  conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json")
  conn.setDoOutput(true)
  conn.connect()

  val wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream)
  wr.writeBytes(jsonHash)
  wr.flush()
  wr.close()

  val responseCode = conn.getResponseCode

  println("Sent: " + jsonHash + " to " + url + " received " + responseCode)

  val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream))
  var response: String = ""
  while(response != null) {
    response = in.readLine()
    println(response)
  }
  in.close()
}
```

It responds with:

```
Sent: '{"schedule":"R/2014-02-02T00:00:00Z/PT24H", "name":"Scala-Post-Test", "command":"which scalac", "epsilon":"PT15M", "owner":"myemail@thecompany.com", "async":false}' to http://localhost:4040/scheduler/iso8601 received 500 

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:4040/scheduler/iso8601
```

stemming from

```
val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream))
```

but if I rebuild it as a `curl` request, it works fine:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"schedule":"R/2014-02-02T00:00:00Z/PT24H", "name":"Scala-Post-Test", "command":"which scalac", "epsilon":"PT15M", "owner":"myemail@thecompany.com", "async":false}' http://localhost:4040/scheduler/iso8601

requirement failed: Vertex already exists in graph Scala-Post-Test
```

(which is what I expect)

Any insight to what is wrong? I'm trying to sniff the packets now to determine what is different.

(Note: I had previously given up on [sys.process._](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247653/using-scala-sys-process-with-curl-single-quotes-and-white-space))

Comment: Use a `PrintWriter` (not a `DataOutputStream`).

Comment: ^^ Ignore that for the time being. While it's not usual to use `DataOutputStream` here, it makes no difference in this case. When you output the `jsonHash` String it's showing your JSON surrounded by single quotes; that's probably the issue.

Comment: Aha! You are correct, single quotes was causing the 500.

--er maybe, nc -l appears to be the same now, but 400 Bad Request. The search continues.

Comment: @Austin run curl with `-v` ... what's the return code there?

Comment: Aha! It also returns 400! 400 is the correct result after all. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
Sent: '{"schedule":"R/2014-02-02T00:00:00Z/PT24H", "name":"Scala-Post-Test", "command":"which scalac", "epsilon":"PT15M", "owner":"myemail@thecompany.com", "async":false}' to http://localhost:4040/scheduler/iso8601 received 500
```

You'll note your JSON is surrounded by single quotes. This makes it invalid.

Also worth noting is that while this code *works*, you are using a `DataOutputStream.writeBytes()` to output your data. This would be problematic if your string including anything but single-byte characters; it strips the high 8 bits off each `char` (Java uses 2-byte chars to hold UTF-16 codepoints).

It's better to use something more suited for `String` output. The same technique you use for input, for example:

```
BufferedWriter out = 
    new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream));
out.write(jsonString);
out.close();
```