# Send Id, Pwd from java to python service simply?

Tags: java, python, service, authentication, httpwebrequest

i am able to connect and get data from python service like,

```
URL url = new URL("http://***.***.*.*:****/list");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(30000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(50000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "GYUserAgentAndroid");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches (false);
                conn.connect();
```

but i am willing to send my id and pwd to python service simply and perform login functionality my python service is ready and just to pass id pwd in it for login. How would i do that ?

Any help would be appreciable

Thanks

Comment: You mean passing your pw and id in form-parameters?

Comment: Passing id , pwd from java form to server in python service.

Comment: What does the python service accept? Form-paramters? Query parameters? JSON? XML? YAML? headers?

Comment: it accept JSON as parameter

Comment: Than it should be POST and not GET. You may not send a payload with get. I think this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268600/using-httpurlconnection-to-submit-a-json-post-request